# play rtsp stream on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtsp

I need to play android rtsp stream for both video audio. But no matter what I do they just don't start. The rstp stream for video is in .mp4 format and for audio it is in .mp3. The stream works fine when played in VLC and it shows the resolution which is 320X240. But here it just give the error which I have posted at the bottom. Also please tell how to stream an mp3 as there is no tutorial in the API Demos in android-sdk. The video works fine with Vitamio Library. But I don't know how to customize it.

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

//onPrepared(...) Function
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
} 

//startVideoPlayback() Function 
    private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

ERROR:
01-05 21:10:59.640: ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(15989): invalid video width(0) or height(0)

Comment: How does this `mIsVideoSizeKnown` get to be true? And where is `mVideoWidth` or `mVideoHeight` get set? Also the logcat is being blunt, width or height is 0!

Comment: ipinak OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
        OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener,         SurfaceHolder.Callback

Comment: t0mm13b it isnt true thats why the video isnt playing. I am just using the API Demos provided by android-sdk btw

Comment: This API along with a lot others are not the best in the world. Also, don't use the simulator.

Comment: ipinak I hardly use the emulator. Currently I am testing on Galaxy S. Galaxy y, Galaxy S2 and Galaxy Note

Comment: The hardware on those devices is pretty good, however you might have problems and inconsistencies with different OS versions. For instance, I tested RTSP streams on a ZTE blade I and blade II, on the blade II, I couldn't play any video, due to timeouts, both were connected over WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onVideoSizeChanged(...) Function into:-

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.d("onVideoSizeChanged: (%dx%d)", width, height);
        mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
        mVideoAspectRatio = mp.getVideoAspectRatio();
        if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0)
            setVideoLayout(mVideoLayout, mAspectRatio);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height)
{
    if(width == 0 || height == 0) {
        return;
    }

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    aspectRatio = width/height;

    startVideoPlayback();
}
```

I would advise you to do this.

Inside the onPrepared method replace `startVideoPlayback()` with `mediaPlayer.start()`

Comment: Didnt work 

01-05 21:47:37.000: ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(18711): invalid video width(0) or height(0)
01-05 21:47:37.906: ERROR/MediaPlayer(18711): error (1, -2147483648)
01-05 21:47:37.910: ERROR/MediaPlayer(18711): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: Can you change to mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); instead of mediaPlayer.prepare(); Though, I'm not sure if this really matters.

Comment: Do you set the display for the mediaPlayer? `mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);`

Comment: yes i have done that .. I havent changed the code except the part you told me do so.

Comment: Can you upload the whole file, because I don't have the sample anymore.

Comment: yes I can do that but the file is too large.. can you provide me with an email id ?